# I am getting undefined index ntoice in php after posting json data through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Undefined index: party_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\partypage.php on line 11
Notice: Undefined index: party_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\partypage.php on line 17
Notice: Undefined variable: party_array in C:\xampp\htdocs\partypage.php on line 43
null

This is my javascript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function(){
         // var jsondata={partyname:"appleparty"};        
        $.ajax({

        type:"POST",
        dataType:"jsonp",
        jsonpCallback:"handleJSON",

       cache: false,
    //   contentType:"application/json",

        data:{"party_name":"appleparty"},
        //    firstName: $("#firstName").val(),
        //    lastName: $("#lastName").val(),
        //    email: $("#email").val()
        url:'http://localhost/partypage.php',

        success:function (jsonStr) {
            console.log(jsonStr);
            $("#partyname").text(JSON.stringify(jsonStr));
        }
    });

        var handleJSON = function(data) {
            alert("received " + data.party_name);
        }

}); 

});
```

This is my php code:

```
<?php

         $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "gigme", "gigme", "a_database");
         if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       echo "failed to connect to database:".mysqli_connect_errno();
         }
        $party_name=$_POST["party_name"];   
        if($_POST["party_name"]!=""){   
        $result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM party_table WHERE party_name='$party_name'");
        $party_array = array();
          while ($party_element = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $party_array[] = $party_element;
          }

        }

    $data=json_encode($party_array);
    echo $data;

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put some information in your question's title... at the moment it tells users nothing unless they actually *view* your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
if (isset($_POST["party_name"]) && $_POST["party_name"] != "")
```

instead of

```
if ($_POST["party_name"] != "")
```

since PHP differentiates between unset and empty variables.

Comment: I still cant get rid of the errors on line11 and line43